# Sending chat history between angular app and v4 Bot Framework Bot (C# + .Net Core Web Application, Angular 8 Frontend)

Tags: c#, angular, botframework

I need a way to send data to my C# implementation of the MSFT bot framework from an angular app with an integrated web-chat window using the directline.

Our specific use case means I need to send a list of messages to a user in teams when a user opens the web-chat window within my angular application. I currently do the following when creating the window:

```js
    window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
      {
          directLine,
          userID: id + '',
          username: 'user'
      },
      this.botWindowElement.nativeElement
  );

    directLine
      .postActivity({
          from: { id: id + '', name: 'webchat_user' },
          name: 'requestWelcomeDialog',
          type: 'event',
          value: 'token'
      })
      .subscribe(
          id => console.log(`Posted activity, assigned ID ${id}`),
          error => console.log(`Error posting activity ${error}`)
      );
```

And then I have this method to handle when a user connects

```
        protected override async Task OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync(IList<TeamsChannelAccount> membersAdded, TeamInfo teamInfo, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (TeamsChannelAccount member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Welcome {member.Name}!"), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
```

I am looking for a way to fetch an object which I send from the angular application to the C# back-end without having unintended side-effects. This object will then be used to re-create the chat history the user created with a different bot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question? Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the example event that is sent when a user joins a chat. Essentially I duplicated that code but created a custom event which handles the data I wanted to pass.
If you are in the same boat as I was when writing this question look into using events with the directline iframe, there's examples already out there that can get you started.